# Selecting a checkbox and using button to check selected checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

So I have this loop and below it is a button,

**Html**

```
       {% for y in 1..cells %}
            <tr id="{{y}}" class="rowDiv">
                {% for x in 1..cells %}
                    <td id="{{y}}col_{{x}}" rel="{{x}}" class="cell colDiv chooser invisible 
                         {% for placement in yourships %}
                            {% for cell in placement %}
                                {% if cell.x_pos == y and cell.y_pos == x %}
                                        hit
                                {% else %}  
                                        no-ship     
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endfor %}                                     
                        ">
                         <input id="check" class="posinput-checkbox" name="position" type="checkbox" data-x="{{ x }}" data-y="{{ y }}" />  
                    </td>
                {% endfor %}    
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}

        <div class="large-3 columns">
            <button>Initiate</button>
        </div>
```

and within the loop is a checkbox, so there will be 10 rows and columns of checkboxes.

Below is a script preventing the checkbox to be checked when clicked

**Js**

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();

return false;

});
```

The questions are how do I make a clicked checkbox "selected" and how do I check the "selected" checkbox using a button?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Please show a snippet of these relevant HTML, rather than the script that generates the HTML.

Comment: You prevent the checkbox to be checked when clicked and after some event happens you want the checkbox programmatically to be selected?

Comment: when the checkbox is checked an image is supposed to show up which is why I tried to disable it from being checked on click because i'm required to have it checked using a button.  @elementzero23

Comment: does twig work for snippets?